# pandas convert object type to float

Tags: python, pandas

I got the a Dataframe with a column like this

```
2011-06-15    8 472,00
2011-06-16    8 432,00
2011-06-17    8 464,00
2011-06-20    8 208,00
2011-06-21    8 504,00
Name: A.P.A, dtype: object
```

There's a space between in the number which I'd like to remove and turn the column into float, so that I may operate with it.

Are there any neat ways in pandas to convert this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with a `pd.Series` called `s`:

```
date
2011-06-15    8 472,00
2011-06-16    8 432,00
2011-06-17    8 464,00
2011-06-20    8 208,00
2011-06-21    8 504,00
Name: value, dtype: object
```

You could:

```
s = pd.to_numeric(s.str.replace(' ', '').str.replace(',', '.'))
```

yields:

```
date
2011-06-15    8472.0
2011-06-16    8432.0
2011-06-17    8464.0
2011-06-20    8208.0
2011-06-21    8504.0
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

Comment: It gives a ValueError: Unable to parse string

Comment: Just saw your number format is different, would need to also replace the `','` - see update.

Comment: Does it have something to do with it not being a string to begin with?

Comment: See updated, there was `.str` missing from the command, sorry. The original `dtype` is `object`, which is how `pandas` represents `string`.